# What is this mushroom and is it dangerous for my dog?

Tags: identification, mushrooms

[image]

I found this giant mushroom in my boyfriend's yard. I found it concerning and I don't know if it is dangerous or not. We have a dog and I'm afraid she will eat it. Does anyone know what type of mushroom this is and if it is something to be concerned about? Any information would be extremely helpful. Thank you. [image]

Comment: Where in the world is your boyfriend's yard? How big is the mushroom -- your photo doesn't give a good sense of scale.

Comment: It's in Massachusetts in diameter it's almost 2 feet

Comment: It's growing in the grass right next to a tree he lives on the water I'm not sure if that has anything to do with it

Comment: Could you post also a picture of a turned up one? It could help to see the pores.

Comment: What a beautiful...fungus/mushroom!  2 feet across?  Shoot make this into a little table...don't think this one is worrisome but will be back with more information.  Mean time cover it with a blanket while your dog is out in the yard.  Take a nap only when the dog is inside the home.

Comment: I agree its one of the Polypores - the most likely reason its there, so close to a tree, is its associated with that tree's roots - if any start appearing on the tree's trunk, remove the tree. This might be a sign the tree has a problem at the root, and this type of fungus occurs on dead or dying wood. Cut it away from the ground if you're worried about your dog, though likely other fruiting bodies will appear over time.

Comment: Thank You so much I appreciate the information. I will post more pictures of it later today.

Comment: I just added another picture hopefully it helps, thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

This looks like some mushroom of the [***Polyporales Order***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyporales), possibly of the [*Polyporaceae Family*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyporaceae). The one in your friends garden probably sprouts on the dead roots or buried a trunk.

It could be this one [*Lenzites Betulina*](http://www.champyves.fr/champignon/fichier_htm/sur_arbres/Lenzites_betulina.html).
[image: Lenzites Betulina Polyporaceae Polyporales]

(credits to [floraitaliae.actaplantarum](http://www.floraitaliae.actaplantarum.org/viewtopic.php?t=58482))

(btw, if you do a close-up of your picture, [google image search knows it's a mushroom](https://www.google.ch/search?tbs=sbi:AMhZZivwZod8mPv3EvM97miHeN5TF4ZrIkv-SfjhNFV_1iVeg7WzAoodKRbWahI5ixORmCaCQPYEtoIzJBsWmnjKMX2aCeqw-64-WZ7Hv4iT3ed8zJyLe7TV4D7ReZYVcK7mWakT7laBxZBYV1HLhsixSbf86ITUHqz6Qzgjb39bFW9SyFOnOCPT2-wIfKFL-5kslFvCpSFIKSZ9rYnlYV46N226JwCqXFWHTmPxRKG7UnORKGa4pA5c15qCAIYFPy2lA63ZkyBBOUpvNVd_1HsL5blJpbAYXSQwvURKm7ku6Q07I1RS7TRWS_13sZWUxlVGGDt3PDEluijKsuuh0JwVAATXMfmHEY-Bg&btnG=Bildersuche&hl=de-CH), and shows many *polyporales* but don't have the right one yet...)

## For your dog:

*polyporales* are rarely poisonous, so small intake should be harmless for a dog.

**But** this kind of mushroom can be very difficult to digest, which can be harmful to a dog that eat the whole thing. But never seen or heard of a dog eating mushrooms. They'd rather go to dead stuff with interesting smell than that.

If your dog takes too much interest in the thing and start eating it, then a possibility is to put a big concrete flower pot over it.